# Error with react testing library and create react app (SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier import ArrayFrom from "./polyfills/array.from.mjs";)

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I know when you have a bare React app, you config webpack to use babel and then jest is using the babel configuration to compile the modules.

Now I have an app created with create-react-app. With a package.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "it does not matter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

With things being like that I wrote the simplest possible test, that passes as green:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

it("renders LoggedUser without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const name = "::name::";
  const avatarURL = "::avatarURL::";
  const loggedUser = { name, avatarURL };
  ReactDOM.render(<LoggedUser loggedUser={loggedUser} />, div);
});
```

Now I follow the create react app docs to add the React testing library:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#option-2-react-testing-library

I follow the steps but when running the test it complaints:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { LoggedUser } from "../components/LoggedUser";

it("renders LoggedUser without crashing", () => {
  const name = "::name::";
  const avatarURL = "::avatarURL::";
  const loggedUser = { name, avatarURL };
  render(<LoggedUser loggedUser={loggedUser} />);
});
```

```
import ArrayFrom from "./polyfills/array.from.mjs";
           ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

In my package I have only added the dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.4"
  }
```

And as the docs suggested created a src/setupTests.js file

```
// react-testing-library renders your components to document.body,
// this adds jest-dom's custom assertions
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

I have tried many things (a .babelrc file with and without a jest.config file...) but I was unable to make the test pass, when fixing one problem another one appeared...

Maybe sb is familiar with this problem and its possible solutions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end what I was trying to do was very twisted because I didn't know very well the webpack-babel-jest delegation when using the create-react-app boilerplate...

So I made another app from scratch and it did work, so I just updated in my real app the `"react-scripts": "3.x.x"` to make it work.

I apologize for all this hassle, anyway digging in the boilerplate was quite educational.

Thank you anyway!